# R - Iteration with Reduce()

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, iteration, reduce

I am currently using a for-loop in order to iteratively compute a variable called "w_ratio", which is a weighted average of "ratio". My for-loop looks like this:

```
  for (i in 2:(nrow(transactions)-1)) {
    if (transactions$type[i] == "Mint") {
      transactions$w_ratio[i] <- (transactions$cum_liquidity[i-1]*transactions$w_ratio[i-1] + transactions$liquidity[i]*transactions$ratio[i]) / transactions$cum_liquidity[i]
    } else {
      transactions$w_ratio[i] <- transactions$w_ratio[i-1]
    }
  }
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
dat <- data.frame(liquidity=c(1,2,3,4,-1,5,6,-2,7),
                  ratio=c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,-0.3,0.4,0.3,-0.3,0.4),
                  type=c("Mint","Mint","Mint","Mint","Burn","Mint","Mint","Burn","Mint"))

dat$cum_liquidity <- cumsum(dat$liquidity)

dat$w_ratio <- 0
dat$w_ratio[1] <- dat$ratio[1]

for (i in 2:(nrow(dat))) {
  if (dat$type[i] == "Mint") {
    dat$w_ratio[i] <- (dat$cum_liquidity[i-1]*dat$w_ratio[i-1] + dat$liquidity[i]*dat$ratio[i]) / dat$cum_liquidity[i]
    } else {
      dat$w_ratio[i] <- dat$w_ratio[i-1]
    }
}
```

The code works well but is very slow due to the for-loop. As I have several million rows, I am looking for another function that makes use of vectorization to compute the same w_ratio variable without using a for-loop. My idea would be to potentially use the Reduce() function, but I do not know how to implement it in this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I just integrated a reproducible example.

Comment: Please also include expected outcome

Comment: Thanks I also introduced the expected outcome (the variable w_ratio)

Answer (score 0):

You may try parallel::mclapply()

```
geti <- function(i, data) {
    if (data$type[i] == "Mint") {
      data$w_ratio[i] <- (data$cum_liquidity[i-1]*data$w_ratio[i-1] + data$liquidity[i]*data$ratio[i]) / data$cum_liquidity[i]
    } else {
      data$w_ratio[i] <- data$w_ratio[i-1]
    }
}
library(parallel)
rows <- 2:(nrow(dat)-1)
res <- mclapply(rows, geti, data=dat)
names(res) <- rows

$`2`
numeric(0)

$`3`
numeric(0)

$`4`
numeric(0)

$`5`
NULL

$`6`
numeric(0)

$`7`
numeric(0)

$`8`
NULL
```